# ZF2 Http Request Issue

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to figure out if I am missing something.

my first code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlParam->asXML());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

this works properly,

Second Code:

```
    $client = new Client($url, array(
        'maxredirects' => 0,
        'timeout'      => 30,
        'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl'));
    $client->setMethod("POST");
    $client->setRawBody($xmlParam->asXML());
    $client->setEncType('text/xml');

    $response = $client->send();
```

this one is the problem,

ERROR from second set of code

> Zend\Http\Response Object (
>       [recommendedReasonPhrases:protected] => Array
>           (
>               [100] => Continue
>               [101] => Switching Protocols
>               [102] => Processing
>               [200] => OK
>               [201] => Created
>               [202] => Accepted
>               [203] => Non-Authoritative Information
>               [204] => No Content
>               [205] => Reset Content
>               [206] => Partial Content
>               [207] => Multi-status
>               [208] => Already Reported
>               [300] => Multiple Choices
>               [301] => Moved Permanently
>               [302] => Found
>               [303] => See Other
>               [304] => Not Modified
>               [305] => Use Proxy
>               [306] => Switch Proxy
>               [307] => Temporary Redirect
>               [400] => Bad Request
>               [401] => Unauthorized
>               [402] => Payment Required
>               [403] => Forbidden
>               [404] => Not Found
>               [405] => Method Not Allowed
>               [406] => Not Acceptable
>               [407] => Proxy Authentication Required
>               [408] => Request Time-out
>               [409] => Conflict
>               [410] => Gone
>               [411] => Length Required
>               [412] => Precondition Failed
>               [413] => Request Entity Too Large
>               [414] => Request-URI Too Large
>               [415] => Unsupported Media Type
>               [416] => Requested range not satisfiable
>               [417] => Expectation Failed
>               [418] => I'm a teapot
>               [422] => Unprocessable Entity
>               [423] => Locked
>               [424] => Failed Dependency
>               [425] => Unordered Collection
>               [426] => Upgrade Required
>               [428] => Precondition Required
>               [429] => Too Many Requests
>               [431] => Request Header Fields Too Large
>               [500] => Internal Server Error
>               [501] => Not Implemented
>               [502] => Bad Gateway
>               [503] => Service Unavailable
>               [504] => Gateway Time-out
>               [505] => HTTP Version not supported
>               [506] => Variant Also Negotiates
>               [507] => Insufficient Storage
>               [508] => Loop Detected
>               [511] => Network Authentication Required
>           )
>
> ```
> [statusCode:protected] => 200
> [reasonPhrase:protected] => OK
> [version:protected] => 1.1
> [headers:protected] => Zend\Http\Headers Object
>     (
>         [pluginClassLoader:protected] => 
>         [headersKeys:protected] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => cachecontrol
>                 [1] => pragma
>                 [2] => contenttype
>                 [3] => contentencoding
>                 [4] => vary
>                 [5] => server
>                 [6] => xaspnetversion
>                 [7] => xpoweredby
>                 [8] => xframeoptions
>                 [9] => xcontenttypeoptions
>                 [10] => contentsecuritypolicy
>                 [11] => date
>                 [12] => connection
>             )
>
>         [headers:protected] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Cache-Control
>                         [line] => Cache-Control: no-cache
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Pragma
>                         [line] => Pragma: no-cache
>                     )
>
>                 [2] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Content-Type
>                         [line] => Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>                     )
>
>                 [3] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Content-Encoding
>                         [line] => Content-Encoding: gzip
>                     )
>
>                 [4] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Vary
>                         [line] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
>                     )
>
>                 [5] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Server
>                         [line] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>                     )
>
>                 [6] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => X-AspNet-Version
>                         [line] => X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>                     )
>
>                 [7] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => X-Powered-By
>                         [line] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>                     )
>
>                 [8] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => X-Frame-Options
>                         [line] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
>                     )
>
>                 [9] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => X-Content-Type-Options
>                         [line] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>                     )
>
>                 [10] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Content-Security-Policy
>                         [line] => Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
>                     )
>
>                 [11] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Date
>                         [line] => Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 12:09:01 GMT
>                     )
>
>                 [12] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Connection
>                         [line] => Connection: close
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [metadata:protected] => Array
>     (
>     )
>
> [content:protected] => ���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��ez��MQ-?�hw��Q�/�լX^|�Ѻ=�>���8����uެ�e���i���e{t��՗��տ�������^�GO�z��������������'oξ|���k��/��.�ߧZ�YY���:�g�y��m�-�l�z�U���v���=M��U]]�|��
> ```
>
> @B�  ���i���

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error it is a Zend\Http\Response object which is returned by the Client object when you call the send method

you can see from the output you have posted that it returned successfully (Http 200 Response).

```
[statusCode:protected] => 200
```

and returned some zipped content

```
[content:protected] => ���...
```

You just need to call:

```
$response->getBody();
```

which will return the decoded content body of the response

See https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.http.response.html for more details